# MySQL can't open files after updating server: errno: 24

Tags: 12.04, server, mysql

**Ubuntu:** 12.04 LTS (Linux mysql02 3.2.0-40-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 25 21:22:10 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

**MySQL:** Ubuntu distro 5.5.31

**Apparmor:** REMOVED!

Server has been running rock solid for over a year. Then this Monday MySQL began failing. An update has caused the problem and we cannot figure it out what it is. We have even tried to roll back to MySQL 5.5.30 but with no luck. We returned at 5.5.31.

**MySQL error log entries:**

```
130430  7:55:46 [ERROR] Error in accept: Too many open files
130430  7:55:46 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't open file: './eci_elite_test/fclvod.frm' (errno: 24)
130430  7:55:46 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't open file: './eci_elite_test/fcnote.frm' (errno: 24)
130430  7:55:47 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't open file: './eci_elite_test/ffcont.frm' (errno: 24)
130430  7:55:47 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't open file: './eci_elite_test/ffcontv.frm' (errno: 24)
130430  7:55:47 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't open file: './eci_elite_test/ffnote.frm' (errno: 24)
130430  7:55:47 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't open file: './eci_elite_test/frcfcl.frm' (errno: 24)
```

It appears we are running into ulimit problem. We have removed APPARMOR completely. We have increased the **/etc/security/limits.conf** and still no luck:

```
# Out of desperation....
* soft  nofile  49152
* hard  nofile  65536

# No effect!?!!?
#mysql  soft  nofile  49152
#mysql  hard  nofile  65536
```

And to show the **limits.conf** is working:

```
root@mysql02:/etc/security# ulimit -Sa | grep "open files"
open files                      (-n) 49152

root@mysql02:/etc/security# ulimit -Ha | grep "open files"
open files                      (-n) 65536
```

And here are the important entries in **my.cnf**

```
[mysqld_safe]
open_files_limit = 16384

[mysqld]
open_files_limit = 16384
```

However:

```
root@mysql02:/etc/mysql# mysqladmin -u root -pThePassword variables| grep open_files_limit
open_files_limit                                  | 1024
```

We are totally stumped and down. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error messages are there in the logs BEFORE the one about Too Many Open Files? You have restarted mysqld since changing open_files_limit, right?

Comment: yes, we have restarted MySQL every time we make changes.
We have one table that is being reported as missing (and it is for some reason):
    30430  8:36:39  InnoDB: Error: trying to open a table, but could not
InnoDB: open the tablespace file './oti_lw_prod/apinvoice_charges.ibd'!

Comment: FYI, we moved our users to our other master (duel master setup) sever (01) and it is now exhibiting the exact same symptoms. It (01) had the same exact configuration as this failing server (02) and is our fail over master should this one (02) die. Well, so much for that plan. We are pretty sure this is an OS problem.

Comment: I'm sure this didn't work for the Original Poster, but for me this happened after a security update, and restarting mysql was enough.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**OS:** Ubuntu (Debian) deployments

**MySQL Server Option:** open-files-limit

It seems that the Debian *upstart* doesn't use the parameters defined in **/etc/security/limits.conf**, so when you launch mysql through the **service** command (and so, under upstart), it overrides those defined limits and uses the default 1024.

The solution is to modify the **mysql.conf** file that defines the upstart service, it is located in **/etc/init/mysql.conf** and add the following lines *before* the **pre-start** block:

```
# NB: Upstart scripts do not respect
# /etc/security/limits.conf, so the open-file limits
# settings need to be applied here.
limit nofile 32000 32000
limit nproc 32000 32000
```

References:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/440878/changing-open-files-limit-in-mysql-5-5
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#c12634

Comment: Disappointing this isn't documented clearly somewhere. :(
We just happened upon David's post on serverfault.

Comment: And this isn't a bug, according to this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/mysql-server/+bug/938669

Comment: This can become suddenly, and alarmingly, apparent after adding partitions to tables which can cause an increase in open files.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 15.10. After upgrading packages got tons of 'Can't open file' error messages, which broke all my sites :(... Thanks a million for saving me a lot of headache and time.

Comment: can anyone explain what is the "pre-start" block?  I'm running Ubuntu 16 and having this issue but the config file looks different than it did previously

Comment: I was confused by this also, but it's not a bug.  [Linux PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM) is a system for authenticating user sessions, and PAM uses the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file. Starting processes using upstart, or forking processes as different users from a non-user session will not use PAM, and thus will not consider `limits.conf`.  This is by design.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem on Ubuntu 15.10.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.6/+bug/1434758 - brought the solution:

1. check if /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service or /lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service is existing
2. (in my case) if not, create /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service and copy content of to this file https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.6/+bug/1434758/comments/11 and add the two lines somewhere in the file

   ```
   LimitNOFILE=infinity
   LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
   ```
3. if one or both files existing, check if this two lines are included:

   ```
   LimitNOFILE=infinity
   LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
   ```
4. execute `systemctl daemon-reload`

... and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

As none of the above fixed the problem for me (only lead to the system running out of memory), here's the solution I found:

In `/etc/mysql/my.conf` you need to increase MySQLs internal open_files_limit. So temporarily add this to the configuration and restart MySQL.

```
[mysqld]
open_files_limit = 100000
```

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

After running the operation that gives you the *too many open files* error, you can change your configuration back to its default and restart MySQL again.

Comment: this worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the workaround. But for me, the issue has been overshadowed by the two other facts.

1. My data directory is different from default installation. For multiple reasons, both historical and technical.
2. I was upgrading from a very old installation, that gone through a number of back- and forward-ports. On the first start of a newly installed MySQL 5.5, the InnoDB engine was not activated (internal implementation was disabled in configuration file, but plugin that was available in previous versions is not present in 5.5), and the upgrade mark was created without actually upgrading any tables.

After fixing InnoDB issue, it was still spitting

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of '.' (errno: 24)
```

I had to start mysqld in root console and manually restart

```
/usr/bin/mysql_upgrade --defaults-extra-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf --force
```

Then the server started to show databases, but unable to access some of the tables. Your workaround with increased limits fixed the rest of the issues, thank you!